# Elements from xml identify add and count (javascript/php)

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I would like some pointers to get me going on this, I don't know where to start, so I would appreciate some help. I have an (or +) xml files in this format:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <Standings>
          <Team Rank="1" Name="fsdfsdf, fsfsdaf" DCI="UNIQUENUMBERHERE" MatchPoints="6" MatchResultsPWDB="2/2/0/0" OpponentMatchWinPercent="50" GamesWinPercent="66,6667" OpponentsGameWinPercent="50" />
          <Team Rank="2" Name="dasdasd, asdasd" DCI="UNIQUENUMBERHERE" MatchPoints="6" MatchResultsPWDB="2/2/0/0" OpponentMatchWinPercent="41,5" GamesWinPercent="80" OpponentsGameWinPercent="36,6667" />
        </Standings>
```

What I want to do is:

(1) extract the DCI that would be the key value, an unique integer, and for every DCI add the MatchPoints and get the name.
(2) will be adding more reports (xml) to that, so multiples occurrences do the same DCI should appear (and add the points and return only one).
(3) return xml formated (to later process and add other reports - recursive point 2).
(4) option to export in htmlt table, but after i manage to extract the values it would be just a formating output change.

First I thought in a regular expression to extract all the values to arrays and after that check the keyvalue (DCI) and add the totals and get a final array and export from there. But after a google search I've seen that javascript and php have functions to deal with xml, but didn't see anything similar to what I was looking for.

Some help on the best line of action or some quick example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

so i solved it using regular expressions, here's the code if someone is interested or want to give it performance/security updates.

```
//get the strings from form with POST
$xmldb = $_POST["xmldb"];
$xmlup = $_POST["xmlup"];
// regular expression
$re = "/<team rank=\"\\d+\" Name=\"([a-z, ]+)\" dci=\"([0-9]+)\" matchpoints=\"(\\d+)\" MatchResultsPWDB=\"([0-9]+)\\//mi"; 
preg_match_all($re, $xmldb, $matches);
preg_match_all($re, $xmlup, $matchesup);

$bd = Array();
for ($i = 0; $i <=  sizeof($matches[1]) -1;$i++  ) {
        //print($i);
        $bd[$matches[2][$i]] = Array
                        (
                        $matches[1][$i], //NOME
                        $matches[3][$i],  // PONTOS
                        $matches[4][$i]  // MATCHES
                        )
                    ;

}
$update = Array();
for ($i = 0; $i <=  sizeof($matchesup[1]) -1;$i++  ) {
        print($i);
        $update[$matchesup[2][$i]] = Array
                        (
                        $matchesup[1][$i], //NOME
                        $matchesup[3][$i],  // PONTOS
                        $matchesup[4][$i]    // MATCHES
                        )
                    ;

}
//update bd with new values
foreach ($update as $key => $val) {
    if (array_key_exists($key,$bd)) { $nome = $update[$key][0]; $pontos = $update[$key][1] + $bd[$key][1]; $jogos =  $update[$key][2] + $bd[$key][2]; $bd[$key] = Array($nome,$pontos,$jogos); }
    else $bd[$key] = $val;
}
```

Still missing the sort option (printing is easy), need to sort by two parameters, but i believe i will figure it out.